# Why can't I change an HTML property at the same time as src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a `muted` video tag with a `src`. I'm able to un-mute the video programmatically, but not if I change the `src` at the same time (order irrelevant). Any ideas why that may be? Here's an example:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
 // If you comment out this line and src doesn't change, it works.
 $('#video').prop('src', 'http://webm.land/media/1KM9.webm');

 $('#video').prop('muted', false);
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" autoplay muted src="http://webm.land/media/KLNV.webm" width="400" height="200" />
```

Comment: But if the first video isn't muted, then the new one isn't muted either. And also the order of muting and changing src doesn't seem to make any difference. Any thoughts on how to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#video').removeAttr('muted');
  $('#video').prop('src', 'http://webm.land/media/1KM9.webm');
  document.getElementById('video').muted = false;
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" autoplay muted src="http://webm.land/media/KLNV.webm" width="400" height="200" />
```

It works!

Comment: OP is not expecting this..He wants to `unmute` it for second video

Comment: @Rayon Yes, it works. Try yourself in my code snippet.

Comment: This is very surprising. Any idea why this is needed when you change src? My best guess is that modifying src queues the element to be changed within the DOM, so property changes only affect the old element.

Answer (score 2):

> Remove both `attribute` and `property` `"muted"` from the element as even if attribute is removed, `property` remains `true`!

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#video').removeAttr('muted');
  console.log($('#video').prop('muted'));
  $('#video').prop('muted', false);
  $('#video').prop('src', 'http://webm.land/media/1KM9.webm');
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" autoplay muted="muted" src="http://webm.land/media/KLNV.webm" width="400" height="200" />
```

Comment: Thanks Rayon! While your answer is clearer, I'm accepting Cesar's because he got it first, but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing `muted` attribute using `.removeAttr()`,  `.clone()` original jQuery object, replacing original `<video>` element with cloned element with `.replaceWith()`

```js
setTimeout(function(video){
  video.replaceWith(video.clone().removeAttr("muted")
  .prop("src", "http://webm.land/media/1KM9.webm")) 
}, 3000, $("#video"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" autoplay muted src="http://webm.land/media/KLNV.webm" width="400" height="200" />
```

Comment: I am not the one..But this does not work.. _Tested!_

Comment: @Rayon _"I am not the one..But this does not work.. Tested!"_? See stacksnippets at updated post. Can you post link to jsfiddle demonstrating "does not work"?

Comment: If you go through the code OP has posted, it has `muted` attribute in markup.. Test it with that..

Comment: @Rayon Have you tried approach at updated stacksnippets?